# Optimize TSQL Except

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I could optimize the join if I could include the ID from table `MasterStaging` (staging table):

- Including the ID in the `EXCEPT` will distort the results since the `ID` from `MasterStaging` will always be different from `StatusComparison`
- `MasterStaging.ID` is irrelevant, just an autonumber, and does not represent the customer ID
- The SQL is designed to show missing customers, regardless of ID.
- The CustomerAccountNo is not a unique number

How can I include obtain the ID top optimize the `JOIN`?

This is what I want:

Same SQL as below, but I will `JOIN` only using `ID`

```
) x ON e.ID = x.ID
```

Here is what I have so far:

```
UPDATE ecl.MasterStaging 
SET NewAccount = 1
    FROM ecl.MasterStaging e WITH (NOLOCK)
    JOIN (
          SELECT  
              ISNULL(Usable, 0) AS Usable ,
              ISNULL(TypeRC, 0) AS TypeRC ,
              ISNULL(CustomerNumber, 0) AS CustomerNumber ,
              ISNULL(CustomerAccountNo, 0) AS CustomerAccountNo ,
              ISNULL(LoadProfileClass, 0) AS LoadProfileClass ,
              ISNULL(MeterNo, 0) AS MeterNo ,
              ISNULL(PrimaryPhoneNumber, 0) AS PrimaryPhoneNumber ,
              ISNULL(CustomerName1, 0) AS CustomerName1 ,
              ISNULL(ServiceAddress1, 0) AS ServiceAddress1 ,
              ISNULL(ServiceCity, 0) AS ServiceCity ,
              ISNULL(ServiceState, 0) AS ServiceState ,
              ISNULL(ServiceZip, 0) AS ServiceZip ,
              ISNULL(BillingAddress1, 0) AS BillingAddress1 ,
              ISNULL(BillingCity, 0) AS BillingCity ,
              ISNULL(BillingState, 0) AS BillingState ,
              ISNULL(substring(BillingZip, 1, 5), 0) as BillingZip ,
              ISNULL(substring(BillingZip4, 7, 4), 0) as BillingZip4
          FROM    
              ecl.MasterStaging WITH (NOLOCK)           

          EXCEPT

           SELECT  Usable ,
            TypeRC ,
            CustomerNumber ,
            CustomerAccountNo ,
            LoadProfileClass ,
            MeterNo ,
            PrimaryPhoneNumber ,
            CustomerName1 ,
            ServiceAddress1 ,                   
            ServiceCity ,
            ServiceState ,
            ServiceZip ,
            BillingAddress1 ,                   
            BillingCity ,
            BillingState ,
            BillingZip ,
            BillingZip4 
    FROM    ecl.StatusComparison  WITH (NOLOCK)
    WHERE   [Status] <> 'D'
            ) x
    ON 
            ISNULL(e.Usable,0) = x.Usable AND 
            ISNULL(e.TypeRC,0) = x.TypeRC AND 
            ISNULL(e.CustomerNumber,0) = x.CustomerNumber AND 
            ISNULL(e.CustomerAccountNo,0) = x.CustomerAccountNo AND
            ISNULL(e.LoadProfileClass,0) = x.LoadProfileClass AND
            ISNULL(e.MeterNo,0) = x.MeterNo AND
            ISNULL(e.PrimaryPhoneNumber,0) = x.PrimaryPhoneNumber AND
            ISNULL(e.CustomerName1,0) = x.CustomerName1 AND
            ISNULL(e.ServiceAddress1,0) = x.ServiceAddress1 AND 
            ISNULL(e.ServiceCity,0) = x.ServiceCity AND
            ISNULL(e.ServiceState,0) = x.ServiceState AND
            ISNULL(e.ServiceZip,0) = x.ServiceZip AND
            ISNULL(e.BillingAddress1,0) = x.BillingAddress1 AND
            ISNULL(e.BillingCity,0) = x.BillingCity AND
            ISNULL(e.BillingState,0) = x.BillingState AND
            ISNULL(e.BillingZip,0) = x.BillingZip AND
            ISNULL(e.BillingZip4,0) = x.BillingZip4
```

Answer (score 1):

One idea, but that might not be ideal : you could create a computed and persisted column on both tables that will calculate a checksum of all columns, and you could join on it. There are risks of collision though :

(I didn't test the code, let me know if there is an error) :

```
ALTER TABLE ecl.MasterStaging
ADD hash AS CHECKSUM(Usable ,
            TypeRC ,
            CustomerNumber ,
            CustomerAccountNo ,
            LoadProfileClass ,
            MeterNo ,
            PrimaryPhoneNumber ,
            CustomerName1 ,
            ServiceAddress1 ,                   
            ServiceCity ,
            ServiceState ,
            ServiceZip ,
            BillingAddress1 ,                   
            BillingCity ,
            BillingState ,
            BillingZip ,
            BillingZip4 ) PERSISTED
```

drawbacks :

- more storage
- more computation during inserts and updates
- you need to change the structure of your table
- it won't work if you need to compare on a LOB